# Como puedo generar fechas faltantes en una consulta en MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla de donde obtengo unos servicios por fechas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesitaría autorellenar la fecha del 2022-02-13 que no existe en la base de datos con valor 0. Quedando de la siguiente forma.

2022-02-11  30

2022-02-12  21

**2022-02-13   0**

2022-02-14  12

2022-02-15  18

2022-02-16  18

2022-02-17  18

2022-02-18  6

Gracias por la ayuda que puedan aportar.

Comment: Necesitas una tabla calendario con las fechas a agregar.. no se van a generar solas.. o un proceso que las genere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta de fechas continuas entre INICIO y FIN puedes hacerla con la que te pongo a continuación, y después hacer un LEFT JOIN a tu tabla

```
SELECT ADDDATE('2022-02-11', INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY) AS DAY
FROM (
SELECT a.a
FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
) a
JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) r1
WHERE 
@i < DATEDIFF('2022-02-18', '2022-02-11')
```

Comment: No deberías haberle respondido ya que no hay ni un mínimo intento, por lo que te recomiendo que elimine la respuesta.